# MEMSql user defined variable

Tags: sql, sql-injection, singlestore

I have found that `MEMSql` does not support user defined variables ([source](https://docs.memsql.com/v5.7/docs/mysql-features-unsupported-in-memsql)).

Is there any workaround of this? Is it going to be in future releases?

I want to do `SQL` injection protection via user defined variables. Is there any other good way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future 6.0 release, you can define stored procedures etc and use variables within those - [see the documentation](https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.0/create-procedure/). A beta is available now [here](http://www.memsql.com/beta).

As for SQL injection protection, most client drivers support running queries with parameters in a way that is not vulnerable to SQL injection. Usually there is a function like `query("select * from t where a = ?", 5)` which places your params in the query in a safe way.